# Projection of fine mesh with low degree polynomial to projection of coarse mesh with higher degree polynomial of a funtion $u$.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

One way of improving some finite element approximations is to take the approximate solution and project it (mesh element-wise) using $L^2$-inner product onto a space of piecewise polynomials of higher degree than the finite element approximation space but on a coarser mesh, which in some cases can be shown to reduce the global $L^2$-error.

My question is whether a similar improvement in error can be had with simple element-wise $L^2$-projection replacing the finite element approximation.

If we assume u satisfies the Laplace equation on our domain $\Omega$ (bounded, Lipshitz boundary) and having $H^s$ regularity for some $s$ with $1\le s\le k+1$,  and we approximate a function $u$ by 1) first projecting onto a space of piecewise polynomials of degree $\leq k $ on a regular mesh of max diameter $h$ (this is the part replacing the finite element approximation), and then 2) projecting the latter projection again onto a space $L_\tau \subset H^{s-2}$ of piecewise polynomials of degree $\le  r$ on a mesh of max diameter $\tau$ which is chosen based on $h$ by $\tau = h^{(k+s-1)/(r+1-min(0,2-s))}$, then we are seeking that

$$\|u - Q_\tau Q_h u\| \le C h^{\frac{(k+s-1)(r+1)}{(r+1-min(0,2-s))}} (\|u\|_{r+1} + \|u\|_{k+1})$$
where $C$ is independent of the mesh size $h$, and the $Q$'s represent $L^2$-projections onto the respective polynomial spaces over the two meshes.

I'm looking for any advice as to whether this is a known result, or any hints about prooving it.  It is to be used in part of a larger proof concerning finite element error analysis, but it's interesting in that it doesn't directly involve any particular finite element method.